# Чем можно заменить слово "попозировать"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, синонимы

*Попросил ребят **попозировать** на фоне гор.*
На мой взгляд звучит не очень хорошо.

Comment: Да нормально звучит, если не задумываться. В быстрой повседневной речи никто и не подумает, что не очень звучит.

Comment: Word подчеркивает все слова с приставкой по- (подешевле, поновее, попроще) как разговорные.

Answer (score 2):

Есть простой вариант: **Попросил ребят сняться на фоне гор.** Но здесь речь может идти об одной фотографии.

Другой вариант: **Предложил ребятам (сделать, провести)  фотосессию на фоне гор.**

**Фотосессия** — процесс фотографирования одного или **нескольких людей** фотографом. Фотосессии как правило происходят в студии (студийная фотосессия) или на открытом воздухе (выездная фотосессия **на фоне** исторического объекта). [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фотосессия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Примечание**

Существует сленговое слово ***фотосет*** (набор фотографий)

Фотосет (англ. photoset) — **сленговое слово**, которое является производным от «photo» — фото и «set» – набор. Другими словами, фотосет это просто набор фотографий, обычно сделанных в рамках одной фотосессии.

Comment: Сфотографироваться.  /* В разговорной речи слово тяжелое, а для письменной - самое то */

Comment: Сфотографироваться - это опять же  можно понять, как сделать одну фотографию. А здесь речь идет о ряде снимков.